# Angular Material Date picker. How to show only years from range (Ex: i need to show only the dates from 1950 to now) remaining years shouldn't show

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-7

I am using Angular material Datepicker for date selection in My project. can anyone have a Solution to show years from a particular range.

Ex: I want to show years from 1950 in my Material Date Picker. years before 1950 should be removed from Datepicker. is there any solution for this from Angular Material.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested below code.Declare  minDate and use it in  tag

typescript code

```
export class DatepickerMinMaxExample {
  minDate: Date;


  constructor() {

    this.minDate = new Date(1950, 0, 1);

  }
}
```

html Code (Use [min]="minDate" )

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: i used [min] but it will disable the previous years it is not removing those years from DOM

Comment: Try this link. if you edit min date to 1950, back arrow for year gets disable.  https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndkgpabgmxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.ts

Comment: in the above stackblitz is ok for min max i need to remove before years from html in datepicker

Comment: But is it possible not to show those years, months and day which are outside the min and max values?